# Mysql auto update event

Tags: php, mysql, database, events

using php and MySql, is there anyway to get the date in the database to update by its self when a date has expired. i.e. event name x is on date 2012-05-12, on 2012-05-13 the date should change to 2012-05-19 (a week from 2012-05-12)

thanks guys

Comment: aa cron job should do it, but are you sure that is your problem?

Comment: Well Im just wondering if this is At all possible I don't really know where to begin. What is aa corn? Thanks.

Comment: A cron job is a unix utility. It is used to schedule jobs. In simple terms, what you have to do is, 1. Write a php script to update table with the desired date and lets call it "update_script.php". 2. Create a cron job in unix which should call update_script.php and schedule that job to run every week.

Comment: o i see, ok thanks for the input i'll look into it. i wasnt sure that i could do that witch a php script thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming that i'd have to create an equation for the mysql weekly update correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html):

```sql
CREATE EVENT update_date ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS CURDATE() DO
  UPDATE events_table
  SET    event_date = ADDDATE(event_date, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
  WHERE  event_date < CURDATE();
```

In order to make the event scheduler run you can add this in my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
...
event_scheduler=ON
```

and with superuser privileges, you can set the global variable on the fly:

```sql
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler='ON';
```

Comment: For some reason I can't turn the event handler on when I'm logged into MyAdmin